# Next.js 13 server component not refreshing data

Tags: next.js

I have a problem with the server component in Next.js 13.4.6

All the time when I load the page the old data from FIRST fetch is displayed. If I refresh the page new data is loaded, but it doesn't save (as you can see in the video). Below I paste the code. What could be wrong here?

[Showcase video](https://i.imgur.com/VaeBuiL.mp4)

```
async function getData() {
    const res = await fetch(process.env.NEXT_PUBLIC_PRODUCTS_API_URL, { next: { cache: 'no-store' } })

    if (!res.ok) {
        throw new Error()
    }

    return res.json()
}

export default async function Offers() {
    let data;

    try {
        data = await getData()
    } catch (error) {
        return <span>{error.message}</span>
    }

    if (data.length === 0) return <span>No available offers</span>

    console.log(data.length)

    return <>
        <span className="text-zinc-500">Found {data.length} offers</span>
        <div><pre>{JSON.stringify(data, null, 2)}</pre></div>
    </>
}
```

I tried using no store cache option (as you can see in code) in fetch options but it didn't work.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The cache option isn't a child of next, it should be referenced like below. Hopefully, this should sort your issue!

```
const staticData = await fetch(`https://...`, { cache: 'no-store' })
```

**Ref:** https://nextjs.org/docs/app/api-reference/functions/fetch

Comment: Oh man, I'm blind. Thanks for your help! Mowing dozens of acres of grass with a tractor is not beneficial to my programming.

Comment: @j2e12r21 Aha, no worries. We've all been there! Well, minus the acres of mowing! 